# Badges are sometimes unreadable in mobile theme

Tags: bug, badges, design, mobile-web

In the **mobile** theme of main (non-meta) sites, *non-tag* badge names are sometimes unreadable: the font color is `#294586` while the background is `#333333`. Examples from Stack Overflow:

#### [Individual badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter)

[image: badge page]

#### [List of badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

[image: badges]

(Those visited are shown in blue).

Seen in:

- Opera 30 on Android 4.4
- Stock browser of Android 4.4
- Chrome 43 on Windows 7 (I know mobile-on-desktop is not supported, but this seems relevant, and was more convenient for screenshots.)
- Mobile Safari on iOS 9.2.1

Comment: It... was already reported. But where?... maybe @Sha will help.

Comment: hmm... found [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257431/visited-tags-and-badges-are-styled-differently-to-unvisited-ones) but looks like it's about the full site theme, not mobile.

Comment: Old mobile browsers and sometimes IE will make all links blue and purple no matter how they're set white. Modern mobile browsers won't do that.

Comment: This was also reported on Code Review meta: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6348/31562 . Still seems to be unfixed.

Comment: Also [reported on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298132/bug-linkcolor-of-visited-badges-on-mobile), and still broken.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been fixed in the updated mobile design.

The link colour does not change when the link is clicked.