# Change foreground text color on SE's new Blog search results pagination links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, blog, pagination

I would like to make a feature request to change the foreground text color of the pagination links shown at the the bottom of search results page on the new Stack Exchange blog.

Try searching for "Joel Spolsky" (or whatever you prefer) on the [**SE's blog search box**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/) (located on the right side panel).

Here is what the current pagination links looks like: (I'm on the 5th page)

> [image]

As you can see, the page number is hardly visible. Here is the relevant CSS code that handles the foreground/background color properties for the pagination links navigation area.

```
.gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-current-page {
    border-color: #333333;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #444444;
}
```

The background color (#333333) is very close to the font's text color (#444444), thus making it hard to see. All we need here is the change of font color which is contrast to its background. For example, I changed the color property value to white (color: #FFFFFF;) and here is what it looks now:

> [image]

With a tiny bit of CSS code tweak we can style the page number to *stand out* from its dark background and make it easier to see/read. I would leave it to SE's UX/UI team as for the selection of foreground and background color property value goes.

**P.S.**

I can reproduce this on the three browsers i.e. Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)), Firefox (Version 39.0) and Safari (Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12)) -- MacBook Pro (Retina, Late 2013; OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2)

Comment: I don't know for sure but I wonder if this doesn't happen to relate to the larger [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260080/take-the-2-minute-tour-inappropriate-color-change-upon-hovering/260096#260096) color [issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257431/visited-tags-and-badges-are-styled-differently-to-unvisited-ones) being experienced elsewhere on the site.

Comment: @Catija I don't think so. This doesn't relates to hover or visited link. You can try clicking on the pagination links and test it. Here, its a bkg. color and text color issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed as of [3de4a2c](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/commit/3de4a2cb8e7c92e688a548b686c8f1a625d12315), thanks for the report!